# How to fix standard input is not a terminal

Tags: c, linux, shell

From an earlier question I was attempting to create something similar to SSH in terms of functionality where a user connects to a machine and can use commands such as `sudo`, `nano`, `vim`.
I found this reverse shell example that seems to do part of the job

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, new_sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    host_addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
    host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to start server");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);

    setsid();
    dup2(new_sockfd, 0);
    dup2(new_sockfd, 1);
    dup2(new_sockfd, 2);


    execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-i", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

but when using the `nano` command to edit a file I got the following message
`Standard input is not a terminal`

and `sudo` does not work properly outputing the message `[sudo] password for user:` on the remote machine.

Is there a fix that allows full interactive remote shell

Comment: You might want to look into [*pseudoterminals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal)